# Jquery ui multiselect widget slow scrolling in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, multi-select, performance

I am using jquery ui multiselect widget on a page which has been constructed with jquery ui layout plugin. a portion(or rather a sub-pane) of the page which contains this widget is scrollable. so when i click on the multiselect it opens the dropdown. now when i start scrolling with dropdown still open, the dropdown stays in it's position and thus gets detached from the dropdown button. To fix this i added a function on scroll event of that div.
it fixes this issue but kills the scroll performance in IE, the code is as follows

```
function initializeMultiSelect() {
    $('.dropdown').multiselect({
                multiple: false,
                // header: 'Select an option',
                noneSelectedText: '-Select an option-',
                autoOpen:false,
                selectedList: 1
            }).multiselectfilter();
    $('.multidropdown').multiselect({
                header: '<a class="ui-multiselect-none" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span>Uncheck All</span></a>',
                noneSelectedText: "Select one or more",
                autoOpen:false,
                selectedList:25
            }).multiselectfilter();
}

function initializeMultiselectFix() {
    $(".center-center-center").scroll(function() {
        if($('#currentSelectedTab').val() == 1 || $('#currentSelectedTab').val() == 2 || $('#currentSelectedTab').val() == 4 ) {
            $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible").hide();
            $(".ui-multiselect:visible").removeClass('ui-state-active');
            $(".ui-datepicker:visible").hide();
            $(".ui-autocomplete:visible").hide();
            <%--if ($(".ui-multiselect-menu").css('display', 'block')) {
                $(".ui-multiselect-menu").hide();
                $(".ui-multiselect").removeClass('ui-state-active');
            }
            if ($(".ui-datepicker").css('display', 'block')) {
                $(".ui-datepicker").hide();
            }
            if ($(".ui-autocomplete").css('display', 'block')) {
                $(".ui-autocomplete").hide();
            } --%>
        }
    });
}
```

This detachment problem can be seen here :http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/datepicker.html
click in the textbox and then scroll.

please point me in the right direction..

Edit: Alright, so i finally fixed the problem. I decided instead of manually hiding the menu on scroll event, let's fix the plugin itself. So what i did was something like this.

i modified the plugin to attach the select menu to append the menu to the parent div instead of document body(which is the  default behavior)

in the _create function

```
menu = (this.menu = $('<div />'))
                .addClass('ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all')
                .addClass( o.classes )
                .appendTo( o.elementToAttach ),
```

and then i passed the elementToAttach property in the options array like this:

```
    $('#dropdown').multiselect({
elementToAttach:$('#dropdown').parent()
});
```

So this fixed a part of the problem, now select menu was scrolling with the div but it wasn't positioned under the dropdown button.

To fix this positioning issue i modified the open function()(which is supposed to open the select menu.)... of the multiselect,  I noticed the position is being calculated using the offset() method which calculates the coordinates relative to the document, but here we want the position relative to the parent so i changed the function to position(), something like this

```
    open: function( e ){
        var self = this,
            button = this.button,
            menu = this.menu,
            speed = this.speed,
            o = this.options;

        // bail if the multiselectopen event returns false, this widget is disabled, or is already open 
        if( this._trigger('beforeopen') === false || button.hasClass('ui-state-disabled') || this._isOpen ){
            return;
        }

        var $container = menu.find('ul').last(),
            effect = o.show,
//the change
    pos = button.position();
```

so everything is working fine now, hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the solution (positioning of the menu) can be achieved using the position API which this widget supports since rel 1.5. All you need to do is to pass an option like this to the constructor:

```
$('#dropdown').multiselect({
    position: {
        my: 'left top',
        at: 'left bottom'
    }
});
```

The first part of the solution (elementToAttach) is still needed. I have suggested the author add this functionality to the widget.